# Why is Pandas df.to_hdf("a_file", "a_key") output increases in size when executed multiple times

Tags: pandas, hdf

Pandas has a method `.to_hdf()` to save a `dataframe` as a HDF table.
However each time the command `.to_hdf(path, key)` is run, the size of the file increases.

```py
import os
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 10**4
df = pd.DataFrame({"C":np.random.randint(0,100,size), 
                   "D": np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size = size)})
for iteration in range(4):
    df.to_hdf("a_file.h5","key1")
    print(os.path.getsize("a_file.h5"))
```

And the output clearly shows that the size of the file is increasing:

```
# 1240552
# 1262856
# 1285160
# 1307464
```

As a new df is saved each time, the hdf size should be constant.

As the increase seems quite modest for small df, with larger df it fastly leads to hdf files that are significantly bigger than the size of the file on the first save.

Sizes I get with a 10**7 long dataframe after 7 iterations:

`29MB, 48MB, 67MB, 86MB, 105MB, 125MB, 144MB`

Why is it so that the hdf file size is not constant and increase a each new `to_hdf()`?

Comment: in `pd.DataFrame.to_hdf()` the default `mode` value is `'a'` which means append.  Try `df.to_hdf("a_file.h5","key1", mode='w')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is not really documented if you look in a fast manner at the documentation (which is 2973 pdf pages long). But can be found in [#1643](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16343), and in the warning in [IO Tools section/delete from a table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.1/user_guide/io.html#delete-from-a-table)  section of the documentation: 
**If you do not specify anything, the default writing mode is `'a'`which is the case of a simple `df.to_hdf('a_path.h5','a_key')` will nearly double the size of your hdf file each time you run your script.**

**Solution** is to use the write mode: `df.to_hdf('a_path.h5','a_key', mode = 'w')`

However, this behavior will happen only with the `fixed` format (which is the default format) but not with the `table` format (except if `append` is set to `True`).

Comment: This works but I wouldn't call it a real solution. Imagine you add multiple items into one HDF file, and then one of the files needs to be updated... You either need to increase the size or add again all other items.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your point! I wrote that question and answer because I could not find this information easily anywhere, and users will likely fall into this trap.
If you have a better solution with multiple keys, I would gladly accept it as the new answer :-) !

Comment: Your answer is satisfactory. I used it and upvoted. However, it may be dangerous when someone accidentally overwrites part of the dataset. That's why this whole issue seems like a `pandas`' bug to me.